# Obtaining address of raw pointer contained in a unique pointer

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a function, which takes a parameter which is a pointer to pointer.

```
 func(**pTmp);
```

Actually this pTmp is a raw pointer and pTmp I get is a unique pointer, so I need to pass the address of the raw pointer contained in unique pointer.
I do it like this

```
func(&pTmp.get())
```

But I get this compilation error.
 lvalue required as unary & operand.

What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: You can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference.

Comment: oh, So what should I do?

Comment: Store the result to a local variable and pass the address of that.

Comment: If you are stuck with this interface looks like you need to use a naked pointer, pass its address to `func` and then wrap it into a smart pointer.

Comment: Be careful -- typically when a function takes a pointer to a pointer, it is because is trying to return a pointer, or it wants an array of pointers.